# Site running by the host entry

Tags: php, server, hosting

I am running one site by host entry and pointing out it to another server.

For example,

My site is www.example.com and I did host entry and pointing it to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP.

When I run URL into browser it is pointing to new IP correctly but internal URLs, JavaScripts and images are calling from it's original old server.

Is it any server configuration issue or something else ?

Comment: Probably just bad coding. Does the code have the old sites urls hard coded

Answer (score 0):

In which technology the website is built with. May be internal URLs, JavaScripts and images are stored in database like in wordpress CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving hostnames to/from IP is a DNS issue. Perhaps your DNS cache is corrupted so try flusing your DNS.

https://www.whatsmydns.net/flush-dns.html